# Rotation Transformation for UITextField, but text is displaced

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to rotate UITextField at 90 angle.It is rotationg perfectly..but text inside the UITextField, is displaced.I am unable to find out the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2):

```
[InputField setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2.0)];
    [InputField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop];
    [InputField setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```

works for me!

Comment: It works, but text become aligned on top, slightly out of center :(

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem? When I apply an CGAffineTransformation to an TextField, everything looks fine.

```
myTextField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the vertical and horizontal alignment (which produces the off-center edit window observed above), you could handle the editing rect manually.  I overrided editingRectForBounds as follows.  This centers the editing rect regardless of rotation:

```
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    // how tall is the font?
    CGFloat fontHeight = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font].height;

    // compute pad 
    CGFloat pad = (bounds.size.height - fontHeight) / 2.0f;

    // return rect with pad on top and bottom
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y + pad, bounds.size.width, fontHeight);
}
```